# Make images be closer to each other

Tags: html, css

I currently have this code

```css
div {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.shirt-container img {
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.all-shirts-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* width: 41px; */
}

.shirt-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-shirts-wrapper">
  <div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-classic-short-sleeve-tee.png"></div>
  <div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-pullover-hoodie.png"></div>
  <div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_womens-premium-semi-fitted-v-neck.png"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is below (image). As you can see, **I would like the images to be closer to each other.**
[image]

Below is my sad attempt of trying to achieve the result

```css
div {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.shirt-container img {
    height: 225px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.all-shirts-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    /* width: 41px; */
}

.shirt-container {
    width: 140px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-shirts-wrapper">
<div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-classic-short-sleeve-tee.png"></div>
<div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-pullover-hoodie.png"></div>
<div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_womens-premium-semi-fitted-v-neck.png"></div>
</div>
```

For specific reasons, **I cannot crop the images**

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhz3kLfj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use image as background like this.

```css
div {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.shirt-container img {
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.all-shirts-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* width: 41px; */
}

.shirt-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 200px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-shirts-wrapper">
  <div class="shirt-container" style="background-image:url('http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-classic-short-sleeve-tee.png')"></div>
    <div class="shirt-container" style="background-image:url('http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-pullover-hoodie.png')"></div>
  <div class="shirt-container" style="background-image:url('http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_womens-premium-semi-fitted-v-neck.png')"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object-fit: cover` to crop the images from left and right at the width  you want (there the images are 225px wide, so let's make them at a width of 170px to remove most of the blanks left and right)

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhz3kLfj/1/)

Comment: Yes, this is another option, make sure to check browser support before using https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```css
div {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.shirt-container img {
    height: 225px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.all-shirts-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    /* width: 41px; */
}

.shirt-container {
    width: 160px;
    height: 225px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-shirts-wrapper">
<div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-classic-short-sleeve-tee.png"></div>
<div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-pullover-hoodie.png"></div>
<div class="shirt-container"><img src="http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_womens-premium-semi-fitted-v-neck.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the images as a background to each div. That may allow you to eliminate the white space to the right and left of each image.

```
<div class="all-shirts-wrapper">
<div class="shirt-container" style="background-image: url(http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-classic-short-sleeve-tee.png)"></div>
<div class="shirt-container" style="background-image: url(http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_adult-pullover-hoodie.png)"></div>
<div class="shirt-container" style="background-image: url(http://awsdevelopment.tzilla.com/artwork/merged/efda3758-f8b5-4d71-8a91-5240dd64aef6-out_womens-premium-semi-fitted-v-neck.png)"></div>
</div>

div {
  background-color: indigo;
}
.shirt-container {background-size:contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;}

.shirt-container img {
    height: 225px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.all-shirts-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    /* width: 41px; */
    height: 200px;
}

.shirt-container {
    width: 140px;
    position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uxwnkets/